# Does firebase analytics on a unity android app automatically tracks user screen views and time on screens?

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I just started messing with firebase analytics, when I build an android unity app, it doesn't seem to automatically track screen time and views per user...it's always at 0min0sec, and screen class is (not set) and screen name is (not set)...
I can see other events but cannot track screen time...
Added Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.SetCurrentScreen(), it doesn't show the time. Has anyone already had this issue ? If so how can I fix that...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Guess I just had to wait...seems like firebase analytics is not in real time like I thought it was...